# How to export multistore product data from DB?

Tags: magento2, database, multistore, csv

My client wants to have a CSV file containing three columns, the product SKU, website ID (1 = CA, 2 = US) and the final price.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run the query below to have the data, it will execute an **INNER JOIN** in the tables `catalog_product_index_price` and `catalog_product_entity`.

#### Export product data via SQL

```sql
SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku, catalog_product_index_price.website_id, catalog_product_index_price.final_price 
FROM catalog_product_index_price 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity 
ON catalog_product_index_price.entity_id=catalog_product_entity.entity_id;
```

☝️ You can use the same query above  to export to a CSV file called **products-sku-price.csv** running this command below. Don't forget to change the MySQL accesses.

```
mysql -h'my_sql_host' -u'my_user' --password='my_secure_password' 'my_magento_db' \
--default-character-set=utf8mb4 --batch --raw -e \
"SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku, catalog_product_index_price.website_id, catalog_product_index_price.final_price FROM catalog_product_index_price INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_index_price.entity_id=catalog_product_entity.entity_id" | \
tr '\t' ',' > $(pwd)/products-sku-price.csv;
```